# SetGlobalSpanCoefficient method google or tools

Tags: or-tools, vehicle-routing

I am trying to use the google or tools for the vehicle routing problem.
Here is the link https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/vrp .
I am trying to use the code by google but when I encounter this piece of code:

```
def add_distance_dimension(routing, distance_callback):
  """Add Global Span constraint"""
  distance = 'Distance'
  maximum_distance = 3000  # Maximum distance per vehicle.
  routing.AddDimension(
      distance_callback,
      0,  # null slack
      maximum_distance,
      True,  # start cumul to zero
      distance)
  distance_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(distance)
  # Try to minimize the max distance among vehicles.
  distance_dimension.SetGlobalSpanCostCoefficient(100)
```

I don't get the meaning of the last istruction

```
distance_dimension.SetGlobalSpanCostCoefficient(100)
```

What's the purpose of this function and what's the meaning of the argument? Why is there a "100" there?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/vrp#distance_dimension), which may very well have been updated since this question was posted, spells out the meaning of the 100:

> The method `SetGlobalSpanCostCoefficient` sets a large coefficient (`100`) for the global span of the routes, which in this example is the **maximum of the distances of the routes**. This makes the global span the predominant factor in the objective function, so the program minimizes the length of the longest route.

In general (from the [API reference](https://google.github.io/or-tools/python/ortools/constraint_solver/pywrapcp.html#pywrapcp.RoutingDimension.SetGlobalSpanCostCoefficient)), the method

> [sets] a cost proportional to the *global* dimension span, that is the difference between the largest value of route end cumul variables and the smallest value of route start cumul variables. In other words: global_span_cost = coefficient * (Max(dimension end value) - Min(dimension start value)).